# Laravel classloader.php error failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am able to run "php artisan migrate" fine. I'm able to get all the form input if I use Request::all() but when I try to add the data to my mysql database table I get the below error:

```
ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 412:
include(Correct_Path/full-personal/database/migrations/2015_07_06_035501_resume_requesters.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I currently have the form attached to a controller method with the below code:

```
 $input = Request::all();
    ResumeRequesters::create($input);
```

I know that I am properly connected to mysql server because I'm able to migrate my migrations.

Any help would be great. Also why did laravel change so many things in Laravel 5?

Thanks

Comment: Tried `composer dumpautoload.` ?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You have to run `composer dumpautoload` inside your project folder.

Comment: Should this be run in production, or locally and pushed?

Comment: @Dazzle You can also run this in production.

Comment: It also solves this error : 
ErrorException include(/usr/share/nginx/html): Failed to open stream: Success

Answer (score 10):

Inside your Laravel project folder:

First, update the composer autoloader ([details](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-))

```
composer dumpautoload
```

then, restart queue ([details](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues))

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Comment: Your answer should have more votes. I think most developers know about `composer dum` by now, but might forget that the queue workers require a restart to respect potential changes, including to the classloader file. At least for me, I forgot to restart the queue, and it boggled my mind why I was still getting an exception about it.

Comment: `php artisan queue:restart` helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me in my Windows 10 machine using a 2 years-old Laravel project from bitbucket. If the `composer dump-autoload` won't work for you, then the error tells you that a directory is missing in my case, there was no *migrations* folder inside the *database* directory.

**Solution:**
Create the *migrations* folder inside the *database* directory. You can do this using your IDE, or Windows's File Explorer. If your using Git Bash, cd to your project's *database* folder then do `mkdir migrations` to create the missing *migrations* directory.

Answer (score 1):

ClassLoader.php Load the given class file into Laravel. Similar errors are due to failure to autoload new classes.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

composer dump-autoload regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php). It won’t download anything.

**When to use:** 
When you have a new class inside your project, Run it from the project root.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason of this kind of error is that when you deleted something from your project like login module then auto-file-loader does contain that file information when you deleted something , so therefore if you are  deleting something , then after deleting something from your project,so shoude run command  composer dumpautoload then it show  following logs
Generating optimized autoload files

> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
>   Discovered Package: facade/ignition
>   Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
>   Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
>   Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
>   Discovered Package: laravel/ui
>   Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
>   Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
>   Package manifest generated successfully.
>   Generated optimized autoload files containing 4334 classes
>   you can run your project again
>   PS D:\laravel\myApp> php artisan serve